# What is a bad, decent, good, and excellent F1-measure range?

Tags: performance, machine-learning, precision, measurement, precision-recall

I understand F1-measure is a harmonic mean of precision and recall. But what values define how good/bad a F1-measure is? I can't seem to find any references (google or academic) answering my question.

Comment: What counts as good or bad depends on how hard the task is.

Answer (score 31):

Consider `sklearn.dummy.DummyClassifier(strategy='uniform')` which is a classifier that make random guesses (a.k.a bad classifier). We can view DummyClassifier as a benchmark to beat, now let's see its f1-score.

In a binary classification problem, with balanced dataset: 6198 total samples, 3099 samples labelled as `0` and 3099 samples labelled as `1`, f1-score is `0.5` for both classes, and weighted average is `0.5`:

[image: strategy_uniform]

Second example, using `DummyClassifier(strategy='constant')`, i.e. guessing the same label every time, guessing label `1` every time in this case, average of f1-scores is `0.33`, while f1 for label `0` is `0.00`:

[image: strategy_constant]

I consider these to be bad f1-scores, **given the balanced dataset**.

PS. summary generated using `sklearn.metrics.classification_report`

Comment: To summarize your answer, anything below 0.5 is bad, right?

Comment: @AlissonReinaldoSilva -- apologies for opening an old discussion, but I don't think it is correct to claim that anything below .5 is bad, because the balance of the dataset is relevant for assessing the baseline to compare an F1 score against. See this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/390541/

Comment: (The answer is not saying this, though. Just talking about your comment.)

Answer (score 7):

You did not find any reference for f1 measure range because there is not any range. The F1 measure is a combined matrix of precision and recall.

Let's say you have two algorithms, one has higher precision and lower recall. By this observation , you can not tell that which algorithm is better, unless until your goal is to maximize precision.

So, given this ambiguity about how to select superior algorithm among two (one with higher recall and other with higher precision), we use f1-measure to select superior among them.

f1-measure is a relative term that's why there is no absolute range to define how better your algorithm is.

Comment: Though if classification of class A has 0.9 F1, and classification of class B has 0.3. No matter how you play with the threshold to tradeoff precision and recall, the 0.3 will never be reaching to 0.9. So in this hypothetical case, can't we be sure that the performance for classifying class A is much better than classifying class B using just the F1 score?

Comment: we compare precision, recall and f1 score between two algorithms/approaches, not between two classes.

Comment: F1 score - F1 Score is the weighted average of Precision and Recall. Therefore, this score takes both false positives and false negatives into account. Intuitively it is not as easy to understand as accuracy, but F1 is usually more useful than accuracy, especially if you have an uneven class distribution. Accuracy works best if false positives and false negatives have similar cost. If the cost of false positives and false negatives are very different, it’s better to look at both Precision and Recall.
F1 Score = 2*(Recall * Precision) / (Recall + Precision)